# Do i have to write AWS Lambda between SNS and PagerDuty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, pagerduty

I have a Snowflake notification error that triggers an SNS topic [like that](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-errors-sns)

I'm trying to figure out the next step for getting PagerDuty alerts.
Do I need to subscribe with the pagerDuty AWS cloudWatch integration URL directly to the SNS and get the alert,
Or should I have to write a Lambda function that processes the incoming SNS messages and send them to PagerDuty?

If it's the second option, I would like to understand the reason.

I subscribe directly to the SNS topic with an email, and it's enough and works. So id like to understand the differences

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty simple setup: https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/amazon-cloudwatch-integration-guide

First, you create an AWS Cloudwatch integration in Pagerduty and make note of the endpoint it creates. Then, create your alert and SNS topic, and put the SNS ARN into the alert's "Alarm Actions" ad "OK Actions". Inside the SNS topic, configure a subscription to be the endpoint of the AWS Cloudwatch integration you created. That should be all you need.

You would only need a lambda in between Cloudwatch and SNS if you want to customize the alert (as seen [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/customize-amazon-cloudwatch-alarm-notifications-to-your-local-time-zone-part-1/)